# ODBC method in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Tags: .net, odbc, enterprise-library-5

I have a requirement of odbc connection method in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data assembly(version 5). Whether it is available in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary ?

Or it there any suitable alternatives for ODBC in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Genericdatabase is used for ODBC in enterprise library.